# Registering asp:button click event handler

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, mouseclick-event

I have multiple asp:button that I created dynamically with jQuery.

For each of them, I have `OnClick="ibtn_Click"` .

But on the code behind, I have to manually register each one of them on Page_Load..like.. `button.Click += new EventHandler(this.ibtn_Click);` .

Is there a way I can register this handler automatically? Or is it possible to register it with ajax jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you created asp:buttons with jQuery? Please post the code.

Comment: Something like this: 

$('<div style="display: inline" id=' + nameTempTop + '><asp:Button runat="server" Text="' + i + '" CommandArgument="' + i + '" CommandName="PageNumber" OnClick="ibtn_Click" /></div>')
                        .attr("id", nameTempTop)
                        .appendTo('div[id='+namePrevTop+']');

Comment: @Jeff: Yes. i had to read again to see whether i had read correctly. ;)

Comment: @Jeff and @conqenator Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Ajax / JQuery executes the code on the client (web browser) whereas asp.net executes the code on the server (web server). What is the use of creating asp.net buttons through jQuery and then wiring its event on the web server?

Comment: Hmmkay.. I'm creating the buttons dynamically because the number of buttons needed are not fixed for all the cases I have. And so, for each asp:button I need to register the event handler.

Comment: Ok, so the question is "How do I dynamically add buttons and handle their click events on the server"?

Comment: Yes, that's the better way of saying it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add ASP.NET web controls in the client's browser. ASP.NET transforms those `<asp:button>` tags into regular HTML, something like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Ok" id="Button1" />
```

When a user clicks one of these submit controls, the browser sends a POST request, which includes the button's `name` as part of the posted data (which you can access via the `Form` collection in ASP.NET):

```
if (this.IsPostBack && Request.Form["Button1"] != null) {
    // do something if the user clicked Button1
}
```

ASP.NET automatically binds server control clicks to the methods specified in the `OnClick` attribute. It calls the method after `Page.Load` completes (for the gory details, see "[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)").

If you're adding the buttons on the client, you can do all this yourself. For example you could "bind" the dynamically generated button in `Page_PreRender`:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.IsPostBack && Request.Form["Button1"] != null) {
        // Call another method on the page
    }
}
```

Finally, in this day and age, if it's appropriate, you should definitely consider just calling page methods via jQuery's `ajax`. See [this excellent Encosia article](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for an introduction to that technique.

Comment: +1 for calling page methods via jQuery's ajax.  The farther from ASP.NET's webform abstraction and ugly postbacks we get - the better!

Answer (score 0):

Is your purpose of generating dynamic asp.net buttons to call code behind?
you can generate html "Submit" button (type=submit) and call webMethods from javascript.
The webmethods are than redirected to you c# code behind