# ASP.NET call C#-function with parameters when clicking on div

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'd like to call a c# function, which is in my model and has to integers as parameters. The function should be called when the client clicks on a div (or something that looks rectangular).
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110274/click-event-on-div-in-asp-net), but I find `System.Web.UI` and for some reason the asp:button also does not find my function in the Model.

Here is my .cshtml code:

```
<div class="playField">
    @for (int y = 0; y < Model.Field.SizeY; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Model.Field.SizeX; x++)
        {
            <asp:button class="bt-box bt-box-@Model.Field.Field[x,y]" runat="server" OnClick="Click(x,y)"></asp:button>
        }
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

and here is my .cs-Code:

```
public class EasyModel : PageModel
    {
        public BoxField Field { get; private set; }
        public SolutionField SolutionField { get; private set; }
        
        public void Click(int x, int y)
        {
            Field.ToggleBox(x, y);
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Field = new BoxField(3, 3);
            SolutionField = Field.AddSolutionField(0.1);
            
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can give me a clean solution ^^

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Did you register the button? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307955/registering-aspbutton-click-event-handler

Comment: Meine Klasse, welche von PageModel erbt, hat keine Definitions namens this.IsPostBack. Also I did not register the button.

Comment: `asp:button` is asp.net component but PageModel exists in asp.net core.What did the target framework you use?

Comment: @Rena I used netcore 3.1